# Как предать переменную с PHP в jQuery?

Tags: jquery, php

Я вот сейчас к одному модулю пишу удаление комментариев, но чтоб удалить тот коментарий, который принадлежит мне, нужно сделать выборку через переменную. Как это сделать, подскажите.

К примеру, такой код. Вот запрос

```
$comment_your=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments_table WHERE post='$id'");
$comment_name=mysql_fetch_array($comment_your); //тут как бы массивчик
$name = $commment_name['name'];
$date = $commment_name['date'];
```

Так структурируются комментарии

```
<div class="comment">
<div class="date">19:14 on 09 Oct 2011 PM</div>
<div class="name">Cgank</div>
<div class="text">Здесь комметарий</div>
</div>
<div class="comment">
<div class="date">16:14 on 09 Oct 2011 PM</div>
<div class="name">frank</div>
<div class="text">Здесь комметарий</div>
</div>
```

Выборку, к примеру, надо сделать так

```
$('$name && $date').hide(); //не уверен что правильно не ругайте
// где $name переменная из php имя а $date время добавления
```

Ну примерно что-то так.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще, вывести переменные можно так:

```
$('<?= $name ?> && <?= $date ?>').hide();
```

Но здесь нужно изучать селекторы jQuery

Предположу, что должно быть так:

```
$('.comment .name, .comment .date').hide();
```

Т.е. спрятать поля `<div class="name">` и `<div class="date">`

Comment: ЗЫ: `$(...).hide()` должно находиться в файле с версткой

Answer (score 3):

Сделайте так: при формировании страницы, перед подключением вашего яваскрипта просто обьявите переменную

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var name = <?php echo $name; ?>;
      var date = <?php echo $date; ?>;

</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/js/your_script.js"></script>
```

И таким образом в вашем js вы сможете обратится к переменным name и data, которые обьявили ранее.